# Does parallel make sense in arbitrary vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces, definition, inner-products

I've yet to come across a non-geometric definition of two parallel vectors in arbitrary vector (inner-product spaces). Does one exist? is it something like:

$u$ is parallel to $v$ if and only if $\langle u^{\perp}, v \rangle = 0$ for all $u^{\perp} \in \{u^{\perp}\}$?

If so, is it true that two parallel vectors are invariant under (invertible?) linear transformations as they are in $\mathbb{R}^n$? For example, any invertible change of coordinates takes a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to an n-parallelipiped. It seems this should be pretty easy to prove in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any choice of basis, by just using the geometric interpretation of the dot product.

Is there a simple proof of this for invertible linear transformations?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for a more interesting condition than $u,v\ne 0$ and $u\ne cv$ for any scalar $c$?

Comment: @Math1000 how does that imply parallel?

Comment: See affine spaces.

Comment: @marshalcraft I had a hunch just the property of being parallel was important enough to have some decent way of preserving it...

Comment: I would interpret collinear vectors as being parallel. But the concept of parallel vectors is much more interesting in affine spaces, as @marshalcraft suggested.